# File URL fails to resolve from bookmark after app restart/rebuild

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am storing file URLs so that they be retrieved on subsequent runs of an iOS app. The URL's are generated from the user selecting local or iCloud files on their device. It seems that the given URL points to a file in `Documents` but which is not actually there.

I have the following code to resolve a URL from a bookmark:

```
BOOL isBookmarkStale = false;
NSError* error = nil;

auto nsURL = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmark
                                       options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI
                                 relativeToURL:nil
                           bookmarkDataIsStale:&isBookmarkStale
                                         error:&error];
```

The bookmark is created with

```
if ([nsURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource])
{

    NSError* error = nil;

    NSData* securityScopedBookmark = [nsURL bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationMinimalBookmark
                                             includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
                                                              relativeToURL:nil
                                                                      error:&error];

    [nsURL stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
}
```

I have verified that the stored bookmark contains the correct URL by checking the last known path with

```
NSDictionary *values = [NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLPathKey]
                                   fromBookmarkData:static_cast<NSData*> (bookmarkData)];

NSString *path = [values objectForKey:NSURLPathKey];
```

Here path contains the last URL to the file. The URL strings from the local files I'm testing with look like this: `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3BFEA0FB-AA84-4CFB-90E5-3535FA14738E/Documents/SomeFile.mp3`

This seems to work while the app is running. But after restarting or rebuilding the app (debug build), then attempting to resolve a URL from a stored bookmark it fails with NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 and the message "The file doesn’t exist."

Comment: I've noticed that the simulator keeps on changing your app's URL as you run it. This won't happen on the device, but to test on simulator you need to store the URL relative to your app's home or documents dir.

Comment: Ok @skaak thanks for the tip. I'm running on a device, as simulator doesn't work when selecting files, perhaps due to the issue you mention

Comment: Yes, to move back to sim you need to make the URL relative. Only the ```.../Documents/...``` part will be stable, but that you get the normal way. I'll post an answer for that ,,,

Answer (score 1):

To get a URL to the user's documents use

```
[NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject
```

This will stay the same on device but will change between runs on the simulator. So you need to make your URL relative to this to test in the sim.

Comment: Please, update this answer so that it makes sense. Imagine that someone is going to read the question and this answer (without comments). This person wont know what do you mean with the _get the URL to the documents and then build from there_, etc.

Comment: Yes completely agree. I wanted to post this into the comment initially but it was getting too clumsy so I just posted it as an answer. But I will fix it up as you suggested soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yea the absolute path could change, so use the relative path.
Just save the part you want after the Documents.

`let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first`

That will be an optional URL (because of the .first), so you might want to

`if let documentsDirectory`

or

`guard let documentsDirectory` 
to make it non optional.

Then you can do documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(pathComponent: SomeFile.mp3)

Comment: The issue seems to be that the file itself does not exist at the path stored in the bookmark. I tried storing the relative path but it didn't work. My assumption is the URL provided is not to a real file, but some kind of temporary thing accessible from the app during the session.